# I am trying to show roles in my !!userinfo command but I get errors

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a `!!userinfo` command and I am trying to get it to where I can @anyone and it shows there info how I have everything else working but then I came up to this problem here is the error.

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

I have looked it up no answer, but I did come up with something it said that it usually means that is unpopulated but I don't know how to get it in there.

```
const Discord = module.require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const userdata = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('commands/storage/userdata.json', 'utf8'));

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    let member;
    if (message.mentions.users > 0) {
        member = message.mentions.user.size()
    } else {
        member = message.author
    }
    let user;
    if (message.mentions.users > 0) {
        user = message.mentions.user.size()
    } else {
        user = message.author
    }

    embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(message.member.username)
        .setDescription("Users Info", true)
        .setColor("#64FF00", true)
        .addField("Full Username:", `${message.member.username}${message.member.discriminator}`, true)
        .addField("ID:", message.member.id, true)
        .addField("Created at:", message.member.createdAt, true)
        .addField("Status:", `${user.presence.status}`, true)
        .addField("Game:", `${user.presence.game}`, true)
        .addField("Roles", member.roles.map(r => `${r}`).join('|'), true);

    message.channel.send(embed);
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "userinfo"
}
```

I Would like it so I can @anyone and there info comes up

Comment: Before you do the RichEmbed, check what `member` is and if it contains a `roles` property, as your issue seems to come from `member.roles.map(r => `${r}`).join('|')`

Comment: @George member does contain roles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem lies with how you assign a value to the variable `member`. Adding to that, I think you have some redundant code since you have a variable `member` and a variable `user` which you give a value with the same code.

Below you can find your code which I've rewritten. Give it a go and let me know what the result is.

```js
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  let guildMember;

  if (message.mentions.members.first()) {
    guildMember = message.mentions.members.first();
  } else {
    guildMember = message.member;
  }

  // We need the User object aswell for different properties
  const user = guildMember.user;

  let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor(user.username)
    .setDescription("Users Info", true)
    .setColor("#64FF00", true)
    .addField("Full Username:", `${user.username}${user.discriminator}`, true)
    .addField("ID:", user.id, true)
    .addField("Created at:", user.createdAt, true)
    .addField("Status:", `${user.presence.status}`, true)
    .addField("Game:", `${user.presence.game}`, true)
    .addField("Roles", guildMember.roles.map(r => `${r}`).join('|'), true);

  message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily make the first part:

```
let member;
if (message.mentions.users > 0) {
    member = message.mentions.user.size()
} else {
    member = message.author
}
let user;
if (message.mentions.users > 0) {
    user = message.mentions.user.size()
} else {
    user = message.author
}
```

into:

```
const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member;
if(!member) return message.channel.send('This command can only be run in a guild!')
```

Also you want to change the embed bit to:

```
let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor(user.tag)
    .setDescription("Users Info", true)
    .setColor("#64FF00", true)
    .addField("Full Username:", user.tag , true)
    .addField("ID:", user.id, true)
    .addField("Created at:", user.createdAt, true)
    .addField("Status:", user.presence.status , true)
    .addField("Game:", user.presence.game ? user.presence.game : 'none' , true)
    .addField("Roles", member.roles.map(r => `${r}`).join(' | '), true);
 message.channel.send(embed);
```

Answer (score 0):

This sets `member` to a number

```
member = message.mentions.user.size()
```

Since `member` is now a number, trying to access `member.roles` results in `undefined`. And since `undefined` does not have a `.map` method, you see that exception.

Comment: I changed it to member = message.mentions.user() still same error